# Dell with LCD issues only boots after it's been off for several hours

Tags: boot, temperature, lcd

A few weeks ago, I started noticing that very rarely, when I touched the frame of my Dell laptop on the left side, there would be a few green lines on my display. I didn't think much of it until some time later, **the laptop stopped booting in over half of the times that I pushed the power button**, instead, it would only beep eight times repeatedly (if I read correctly, the 8-beep pattern refers to an issue with the LCD, which would make sense considering the graphics issue I experienced before.)

Strangely though, out of all those times that I tried to start my laptop (within >2 weeks), there were only 3 cases when the laptop *did* boot on an afternoon/evening, while *all the other times* that the laptop started normally were in the morning. In other words, **every first attempt to start the laptop in the morning (after several hours of being turned off) was successful**. What could be the reason for that?

Being under the impression that there might simply be a loose wire or so inside, I'm planning to open up the laptop as soon as I get hold of a proper screwdriver, but I'm wondering: **Does the fact that the laptop always boots in the morning give anything away about the likely nature of this issue?**

I should say that not being a hardware expert, I have not attempted to cool the laptop down by, say, storing it in a particularly cold location.

Please go ahead and ask for clarification if deemed necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My suspect #1 would be heat--it only boots when cold.

My suspect #2 would be that it only boots when there has been enough time for capacitors to fully discharge.

Unfortunately, I have no idea of how to fix either problem.

Comment: Now that I see your answer I might add that whenever the laptop didn't boot, it would beep (the display issue code). It will boot though if I press the upper left corner of the keyboard. Also whenever it *does* boot, there are "colorful" artifacts all across the screen (green artifacts where there is black, pink where there's white "background"). I would therefore guess that there's an issue with the graphics card. Any idea if it's absolutely necessary to buy a new laptop, or if there's a way to repair this myself?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, turned out to be very simple in the end. https://superuser.com/questions/1088020